# Spring Kafka configure number of partitions for topic

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Is it possible in Spring Kafka configure the number of partitions for the specific topic in order to be able to effectively use `org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrency(Integer)` method to parallel consumers on this topic in order to speed up message consumptions and processing? If so, could you please show the example of how it can be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Configuring Topics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#configuring-topics).

```
@Bean
public NewTopic topic1() {
    return new NewTopic("foo", 10, (short) 2);
}
```

Will create a topic `foo` with 10 partitions and a replication factor of 2 (if there is a `KafkaAdmin` bean in the application context).

Spring boot auto-configures a `KafkaAdmin` `@Bean`.